# PostgreSQL pattern LIKE not matching simple example

Tags: regex, postgresql, sql-like

Hi I don't understand why my pattern does not work. It seems to be the same as in many examples I've seen on the Internet. Can you help?

```
select city from cities where city like 'ny';

56 rows

select city from cities where city like '[a-z][a-z]';

0 row
```

Comment: Show example input data. But I don't know why you think `like` supports regex, when the docs state that other functions must be used for that: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/functions-matching.html "many examples I've seen on the internet" are useless without citation, especially if they refer to other types of SQL.

Comment: all lines are 'ny'

Comment: Character ranges are not part of the standard `LIKE` operator, though some SQL dialects offer it as an extension -- most notably T-SQL, the dialect used by SQL Server, which is probably what your examples are using.

Answer (score 2):

`LIKE` is no comparator for Regular Expressions ([Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html))

You should take `~` comparator or `SIMILAR TO`:

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=2f11390861cf0bf59ba9da08aa76fde4)

```
SELECT
    *
FROM cities
WHERE city ~ '[a-z][a-z]';

SELECT
    *
FROM cities
WHERE city SIMILAR TO '[a-z][a-z]';
```

Comment: You forgot `^` and `$`.

Comment: Well, I just demonstrated the usage of the the comparators ;) If the TO really need to define start and end, then you are right, of course.

Comment: No, you don't need the `^` and `$`.  `SIMILAR TO` (and `LIKE`) patterns must match the entire string/field.

Comment: Thanks for upvoting. Please don't forget to ACCEPT the question as well if it solves your problem! :)